# set a default Cursor icon for panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small `panel` and I want while mouse is on this `panel`,have a certain icon. I can not use `mouse enter/leave event` because it is possible that part of this panel be covered by `toolstips`. I tried `mouse move event` but it glitchs too bad. is there any way to set a default cursor icon for a panel or do what I want somehow?(C#,WinForm)

Comment: Have you also tried considering or excluding `MouseHover` event?

Comment: Have you tried setting the panel's `Cursor` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the panel's [`Cursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx) property, but beware -

> The Cursor property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. For example, a Button will have the same BackColor as its parent Form by default. For more information about ambient properties, see the AmbientProperties class or the Control class overview.

This means that you must explicitly specify the `Cursor` property of everything on that `Panel` back to the default cursor.